# Is it possible to get the Google Cloud Messaging server key using the CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

I'm working on an automation script to create Firebase projects with the GCM API enabled. So far I managed to create the project and enable the Google Cloud Messaging API (`googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com`) by using the following command:

`gcloud services enable googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com`

This has left me with the following configuration on the Firebase Console:

[image]

So my question is: Is it possible to retrieve the Server Key and Sender Id using the `gcloud` CLI tool (or even with some other tool or API)?

Answer (score 0):

You can only retrieve your Server Key by using the Firebase Console UI which is in your posted image above.

You may use this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#:%7E:text=You%20obtain%20the%20server%20key%20when%20you%20create%20your%20Firebase%20project.%20You%20can%20view%20it%20in%20the%20Cloud%20Messaging%20tab%20of%20the%20Firebase%20console%20Settings%20pane.) for reference.